# Build error compiling ExtJS app using Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd5

My build is failing in my ExtJS 5 project - I am using Ubuntu 15 desktop version.

```
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
[ERR] at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeRe
[ERR] verseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
```

[image: Sencha Cmd terminal output]

Comment: Can you provide some code you have tried?

Comment: You can try to run it with `--debug` it can provide you much more info. Btw I have read somewhere that ruby version can affect this, you can try to upgrade to latest, or rather downgrade some older one.

Comment: Have you installed sencha utility for ubuntu system ? How are you doing build.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Sencha Cmd were dependent on [Ruby 1.9.3](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/11/13/ruby-1-9-3-p551-is-released/) or **below**. It's likely this is the cause as Ruby is being used to compile Sass themes and the `[INF]` lines immediately above the error indicate that this step is where the build process is failing.

You can verify which version you currently have by running `ruby -v` in your terminal window.  If you'd rather not downgrade Ruby - you could instead try upgrading your version of [Sencha Cmd](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/) as later versions were patched to work with Ruby 2.

If you do try to upgrade Cmd, the build might complain about differing project and compiler versions - you can run the following inside your existing ExtJS project directory (do a backup first) to upgrade the build configuration independently of the framework:

```
sencha app upgrade --noframework
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I uninstalled sencha cmd 5.1.1 and installed sencha cmd 6, then it worked perfectly, thanks for the support.